# MS SQL каскадное удаление из таблицы при изменении значения записи

Tags: sql-server

Есть следующие таблицы:

```
[dbo].[DocNumbers]
(
   [Id] int primary key identity(1,1),
   [IsDeleted] bit
)
```

```
[dbo].[DocflowDocuments]
(
   [Id] nvarchar(25),
   [DocNumberId] int,
)
```

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы при изменении статуса `[DocNumbers].[IsDeleted] = 1` автоматически удалялась запись из таблицы `[DocflowDocuments]`? Я мог бы добавить foreign key на update, но к сожалению не знаю как отслеживать изменение `[IsDeleted] = 1`

Comment: вам скорее триггер нужен, каскадное удаление тут совсем не применимо

Comment: @Konst мне любое решение подойдет, только вот в sql я максимум inner join сделать могу и то если погуглю

Comment: Гм... а зачем? просто создайте джоб, который удаляет зависимые записи. Скажем, раз в сутки. Во-первых, пара-тройка лишних записей, провисевшая в таблице лишние полдня, на производительности не скажется, во-вторых, при ошибочной пометке к удалению можно успеть откатиться, вернув старое значение поля.

Comment: @Akina нет, раз в сутки это вообще не вариант. Мне надо "здесь и сейчас", я могу в принипе в табилицу `[DocflowDocuments]` добавить тоже `IsDeleted`

Comment: Тогда триггер, без вариантов. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_D_DocNumbers
ON dbo.[DocNumbers]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    DELETE F FROM dbo.DocflowDocuments F INNER JOIN  inserted D ON D.Id = F.DocNumberId And D.IsDeleted = 1;
GO
```

Comment: А какой смысл сканить всю таблицу-то? не проще пообщаться с INSERTED в виде JOIN?

Comment: можно, пусть автор вопроса подумает как это сделать =), хотя тут semi-join используется

Comment: @Konst а можно вы за меня подумаете?)) А то тут просто почти рабочий день кончается, хотелось бы не думать

Comment: поставьте галку на ответе, недумающий наш )

Comment: @Konst а что такое F?

Comment: это алиас таблицы

Comment: @Konst у меня не работает, пишет что `inserted` недопустимое имя. Если его убрать, то `D` - недопустимое имя. Я тестирую сам запрос на delete, сам триггер еще не делал

Comment: где вы пытаетесь выполнить скрипт? проверьте, что вы находись в контексте нужной вам базы данных

Comment: @Konst в ms sql нажал пкм по базе -> создать запрос. Дальше вставил это: `DELETE F FROM dbo.DocflowDocuments F INNER JOIN  inserted D ON D.Id = F.DocNumberId And D.IsDeleted = 1;` и выполнил, не работает(

Comment: надо выполнить весь скрипт на создание триггера. после этого данные будут автоматически удаляться при изменении значения в таблице IsDeleted=1

Comment: Я изменил `inserted` на `docnumbers` и всё заработало. Полагаю `inserted` это название той таблице в запросе вверху `ON dbo.[DocNumbers]`

Comment: вы хотели, чтобы данные автоматически удалялись из 2-й таблицы при изменении поля в первой. Для этого нужно создать триггер (код триггера в моем ответе).

Comment: @Konst да, но я решил протестить то, что внутри триггера. Спасибо вам, всё работает!